# Plotting an integral equation

Tags: plotting

I would like to draw the solution of the following equation in a log-log plot of $\lambda$ against $M$.

$$10^{-10} = \frac{\lambda^{2}}{(4\pi)^{2}}\int_{0}^{1}dz\frac{(1-x)^{3}}{(1-x)^{2}+zM^{2}}$$

Here is my code:

```
table = Table[{Exp[M], λ /. 
     NSolve[((λ^2)/(4 *Pi)^(2)) * 
         NIntegrate[(((1-x)^3)/((1-x)^2 + Exp[2 M] x)), {x, 0, 1}] == 
                                    10^(-10), λ][[2]]}, 
     {M, -15, 15, 0.03}];
 ListLogLogPlot[table, Joined \[RightArrow] True, 
 AxesOrigin \[RightArrow] {1, 1}]
```

With this code, I get a list of error messages and a list of the output values, but not the plot. How do I get the plot?

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Do you want the value of the full expression for different values of λ and $M$?  And what is `AxesoutpOrigin`?  And why use `\[Minus]` instead of -?

Comment: Oh, no! See my edits in the equation and in the code.

Comment: I want the solution of the edited equation. AxesoutpOrigin should actually be AxesOutput. And I've replaced \[Minus] with the minus sign.

Comment: A `\[Minus]` remains...

Comment: all of them now replaced

Comment: Instead of `\[RightArrow]` use `->`

Answer (score 2):

Why not make things easier and solve the integral exactly?

After making the integration variable consistently $\text{x}$ and changing it to $\text{x}\to 1-\text{x}$, the integral can be calculated explicitly. (In order to assist Mathematica in solving the integral we also assume temporarily that $\text{M}<-2$ such that the roots of the denominator are real.)

We get

```
f[M_] = Integrate[x^3/(x^2 + (1 - x) M^2), {x, 0, 1}, Assumptions -> M < -2] //
   FullSimplify

(* Out[111]= (Sqrt[-4 + M^2] (1 + 2 M^2) - M^2 Sqrt[-4 + M^2] (-1 + M^2) Log[M^2] - 
 M^3 (-3 + M^2) Log[1/2 (-2 + M^2 - M Sqrt[-4 + M^2])])/(2 Sqrt[-4 + M^2]) *)
```

$$f(\text{M})=\int_0^1 \frac{x^3}{x^2+(1-x)M^2 } \, dx\\= \frac{1}{2} \left(\left(2 M^2+1\right)-M^2 \left(M^2-1\right) \log \left(M^2\right)\right)\\-\frac{\left(M^3 \left(M^2-3\right)\right) \log \left(\frac{1}{2} \left(M^2- M\sqrt{M^2-4}-2\right)\right)}{2 \sqrt{M^2-4}}$$

The result now holds for all real $\text{M}$.

At the special points it is

```
Limit [f[M], M -> 0]

(* Out[113]= 1/2 *)

{Limit [f[M], M -> 2], Limit [f[M], M -> -2]}

(* Out[115]= {17/2 - 12 Log[2], 17/2 - 6 Log[4]} *)

Series[f[M], {M, \[Infinity], 2}] // Normal

(* Out[148]= (-(11/6) - 2 Log[1/M])/M^2 *)
```

And here's the graph

```
Plot[f[M], {M, -10, 10}, 
 PlotLabel -> "The integral as a function of M"]
```

[image]

Now the function $\lambda $ is defined as

```
ld[M_] := 4 \[Pi] 10^-5/Sqrt[f[M]]
```

A log-log-plot (which is naturally confined to positive quantities) is then

```
LogLogPlot[ld[M], {M, .001, 15}, PlotLabel -> "Log-log-plot", 
 AxesLabel -> {"Log[M]", "log[\[Lambda]]"}]
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Evaluating the integral is a great enhancement.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your graph, once you delete the non-converged values:

```
ListLogLogPlot[table, AxesOrigin -> {1,1}]
```

[image]

Comment: How can I make (1,1) the point where the axes cross?